# show by value of foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I want to show data in asp.net project.

I have tables name `cultural event` and `event_sub category`

**Table**: event_sub category

| id | subcat_name | evnt iD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | solo | 5 |
| 2 | duet | 3 |
| 3 | solo | 4 |

AND

**Table**: cultural event

| ID | NAME | S_DATE | END DATE | ENTRY FEES | ESUBCAT ID | EID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JUST Dance | 2017-2-03 | 2017-2-05 | 100 | 1 | 5 |

Now I want to display an event details from cultural table

```
JUST Dance | 2017-2-03 | 2017-2-05 | 100 on my web page (asp.net) |
```

I want to show event by `ESUBCAT ID` and by `EID`, means want to show solo event from EID=5 or anything as per the requirement.

I am showing in repeater...whats the right way to do it?

I have linkbuttons like:

- solo
- duet
- grup

When user will click on solo he should get the information of event from cultural table by its category. That means he must get info of solo event from `EID` 5 only.

If clicked on `duet` only info of duet cat should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema makes no sense whatsoever, maybe it's bad design or bad naming convention, but it seems that you have data about an event on 2 different tables with two foreign keys.

You have 2 `sub_cats` both named `solo` but they have different `ids` and `evnt_iD`. What's the point?

You are also missing some sort of `aspx` that will display the data you'll get from the `DB`.

Have a look at the following link and create a skeleton that fetches the data and displays it on the web page and then we'll help you out on how to filter it from the `UI`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data

Comment: thank you so much.but i want to do this by sql. actually i want to display data by using foreign key, ted i have two entries of solo but Eid is different that means both are belongs to different college fest